# How to immediately get timestamp value after update?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I've got some client code that is committing some data across some tables, in simple terms like so:

- Client [Id, Balance, Timestamp]
- ClientAssets [Id, AssetId, Quantity]
- ClientLog [Id, ClientId, BalanceBefore, BalanceAfter]

When the customer buys an asset, I do the following pseudo code:

BEGIN TRANSACTION

1. GetClientRow Where ID = 1
2. Has enough balance for new asset cost? Yes...
3. Insert Into ClientAssets...
4. UpdateClient -> UPDATE Client SET Balance = f_SumAssetsForClient(1) WHERE ID = 1 and Timestamp = TS From Step 1;
5. GetClientRow Where ID = 1
6. Insert Into ClientLog BalanceBefore = Balance at Step 1, BalanceAfter = Balance at Step 5.
   COMMIT

On step 4, the client row is updated in 1 update statement using a function 'f_SumAssetsForClient' that just sums the assets for the client and returns the balance of those assets. Also on Step 4, the timestamp is automatically updated.

My problem is, when I call GetClientRow again on Step 5, someone could have updated the clients balance, so when I go to write the log in Step 6, its not truly the balance after this set of steps. It would be the balance after a different write outside of this transaction.

If I could get the newly updated timestamp from the client row when I call UPDATE in Step 4, I could pass this to step to only grab the client row where the TS = the new updated TS. Is this possible at all? Or is my design flawed. I can't see a way out of the problem of stale data between step 5 and 6. I sense there is a problem in the table design but can't quite see it.

Comment: sounds like you need a step 3.5 that is `SELECT f_SumAssetsForClient(1)` then store that value, then do the update, then write the log with the values - you shouldnt have to deal with the timestamp at all -- or do the whole procedure as a stored proc

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Oh that makes total sense now. Basically, anytime after Step 4, the data reads are untrustable. but if I grab all the values before the final UPDATE which is protected by the timestamp check that determines a commit or rollback, and use those to build the report, then it should be fine. Thank you :).

Comment: Well, you run those statements within a transaction, so the common way would be to upgrade the lock in the 1st Select to a WRITE lock (seems to be a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in MySQL), which prevents other sessions from modifying this ID.

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you, glad you pointed this out. I've managed to change how Im saving data in a graph style of tables and it looks like SELECT...FOR UPDATE according to the documentation was provided perfectly for this kind of use case. All I have to do now is make sure I do a SELECT..FOR UPDATE on the parent/header row, then all the branch tables relating to that parent can be safely updated, and I have no worry about timestamp checks etc. One has to bear in mind the time it might take to lock/commit as you don't want to be holding on to the lock for a long time in high transaction environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 needs to be `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  Any other data that needs to change also need to be "locked" `FOR UPDATE`.

That way, another thread cannot sneak in and modify those rows.  They will probably be delayed until after you have `COMMITted`, or there might be a Deadlock.  Either way, the thing you are worried about cannot happen.  No timestamp games.

Comment: Yep, Im going to have to change my answer to this as this is what I used in the end and what seems most correct. What my initial question shows is that I'm dealing with a tree/graph like structure of data and the SELECT...FOR UPDATE is specifically for dealing with this kind of data model.

Answer (score 1):

**Copied from comment**

> Sounds like you need a step 3.5 that is `SELECT f_SumAssetsForClient(1)` then 
>   store that value, then do the update, then write the log with the values - you 
>   shouldnt have to deal with the timestamp at all -- or do the whole procedure as 
>   a stored proc